# Individual created Jena has no class when written in file

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, protege

My java Program is reading medical datas and translate them into semantic and then i save it as a RDF file to export them. But one individual from a specific class is always present in file but some properties and it's class are missing.

I've tried to change the export format, i've double checked all IRIs. All of that was unsucessfull.

I've added some code to check the class and the properties juste before writing the model in the RDF file and everything seems correct.

The code to create ontology :

```
    public static Individual createIndiv(String name, Resource ressource) {                 // Create an Individual
        if (populateModel==null) {populateModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();}
        if (name==null || ressource==null) {
            logger.error("Creating Individual named "+name+" with classs "+ressource.getLocalName());
            return null;
        } else {
            logger.debug("Creating Individual named "+name+" with classs "+ressource.getLocalName());
            System.out.println(ressource);
            Individual ind = populateModel.createIndividual(racineURI+name, ressource);
            return ind;
        }
    }

        Individual imagingStudy = createIndiv(generateName("imaging_study_TEST"), model.getResource("http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#imaging_study"));
```

The test to check before writing :

```
        System.out.println("Test Final :");
        System.out.println("RDF Type :"+imagingStudy.getRDFType());
        StmtIterator propertiesIter = imagingStudy.listProperties();
        Statement p;
        while (propertiesIter.hasNext()) {
            p = propertiesIter.next();
            System.out.println(p.asTriple());
        }
```

The code for Write the model :

```
    public void writingRDF(String pathOut) throws FileNotFoundException  {                                                              // Write the RDF 
        logger.info("Writing RDF file in "+pathOut);        

        FileOutputStream sortie = new FileOutputStream(pathOut);
        OntologyPopulator.populateModel.write(sortie, "RDF/XML", null);                 

        logger.info("Writing RDF file Sucessfull");
        OntologyPopulator.populateModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    }
```

A short RDF file :

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:j.1="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#part_of_study"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#is_about_procedure"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_protocol"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#used_as_instrument_in"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000052"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000087"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000132"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000054"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#years"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_id"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_manufacturer_name"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_description"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_name"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_DICOM_study_instance_UID"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_DICOM_series_instance_UID"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_beginning_time"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_beginning_date"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#has_model_name"/>
  <j.1:age_of_patient_undergoing_medical_procedure rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#age_of_patient_undergoing_medical_procedure_1cf4387d-b276-4f86-8e6d-52eb48833afd">
    <j.1:is_about_procedure>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#imaging_study_TEST_ec26ee5a-c016-4b20-9c90-cce7315ea2c7">
        <j.1:part_of_study>
          <j.1:clinical_research_study rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#clinical_research_study_755523_subtask2.1.2"/>
        </j.1:part_of_study>
      </rdf:Description>
    </j.1:is_about_procedure>
    <j.1:years rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal"
    >36</j.1:years>
  </j.1:age_of_patient_undergoing_medical_procedure>
  <j.1:patient rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#Patient_4c7681a8-176b-4940-abbd-27fb9df399f7">
    <j.0:BFO_0000054>
      <j.1:SPECT_data_acquisition rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#SPECT_data_acquisition_c8bd9ca2-70c1-4cd5-b52b-2295db407922">
        <j.1:has_DICOM_series_instance_UID>1.3.12.2.1107.5.6.1.9225.30500109020320314446800000119</j.1:has_DICOM_series_instance_UID>
        <j.1:has_beginning_time>073900.000000</j.1:has_beginning_time>
        <j.1:has_beginning_date>20090211</j.1:has_beginning_date>
        <j.1:has_id>1000</j.1:has_id>
        <j.0:BFO_0000132 rdf:resource="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#imaging_study_TEST_ec26ee5a-c016-4b20-9c90-cce7315ea2c7"/>
        <j.1:has_protocol>
          <j.1:NM_acquisition_protocol rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#NM_acquisition_protocol_950491e0-2b97-4c5a-89d6-044852ead542">
            <j.1:has_description>Spect 131-I</j.1:has_description>
            <j.1:has_name>7312.0.21354437@</j.1:has_name>
          </j.1:NM_acquisition_protocol>
        </j.1:has_protocol>
      </j.1:SPECT_data_acquisition>
    </j.0:BFO_0000054>
    <j.0:BFO_0000054 rdf:resource="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#imaging_study_TEST_ec26ee5a-c016-4b20-9c90-cce7315ea2c7"/>
  </j.1:patient>
  <j.1:SPECT_scanner rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#SPECT_scanner_39a89288-4f79-49c7-ac18-f59dec9786bf">
    <j.0:BFO_0000087>
      <j.1:image_acquisition_role rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#image_acquisition_role_28318df2-49ec-45a4-a59e-233fc371e729">
        <j.0:BFO_0000054 rdf:resource="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#SPECT_data_acquisition_c8bd9ca2-70c1-4cd5-b52b-2295db407922"/>
      </j.1:image_acquisition_role>
    </j.0:BFO_0000087>
    <j.1:has_model_name>IP2</j.1:has_model_name>
    <j.1:has_manufacturer_name>SIEMENS NM</j.1:has_manufacturer_name>
    <j.1:used_as_instrument_in rdf:resource="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#SPECT_data_acquisition_c8bd9ca2-70c1-4cd5-b52b-2295db407922"/>
  </j.1:SPECT_scanner>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#role_of_responsible_organization_e147d526-332d-40df-8df8-80a63e0b4a22">
    <j.0:BFO_0000052 rdf:resource="http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#institution_700f9e9c-9cb6-461f-b7d6-42a995583523"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <j.0:PATO_0000383 rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000383"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Properties as seen in the test (it's ok)
1 class
4 properties

The Imaging_Study Individual as seen in Protégé
No class
2 properties only

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that writes the model to an RDF file, and show the contents of the generated RDF file (or at least the imaging study part in case the file is large) as it appears in a text editor.

Comment: I've added all that

Comment: The problem here you are using `OntModel` and Protege together, without any understanding even RDF. `OntModel` is only for OWL1. Protege is for OWL2. When you do `OntModel#createIndividual` you are creating class assertion without named individual declaration (`owl:NamedIndividual`). When you load file to Protege, all missed declarations are restored by OWL-APIv4, if it is possible, because OWL API is just guessing and not always successful. To resolve the issue you need add things correctly according to OWL2 spec, possible with `OntModel`. See, e.g. https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference

Comment: @ssz Named individual declarations are optional in OWL 2.

Comment: @ZeeBlueAngel Are you sure that `createIndiv(...)` was executed to generate that RDF file? The method should generate an individual of class `imaging_study` but there is no such individual in the file. What was the output of your test code for that file?

Comment: @cygri can you give me a link to spec? I always thought it can be considered optional, but only if there is a class assertion (`U rdf:type C`), where the right part is definetely class expression (e.g. has `owl:Class` declaration). `OntModel#createIndividual` creates just class assertion, right part is any resource. So Protege may not understand what is it exactly.

Comment: @ssz I think you have that right. In OWL 2, a statement `U rdf:type C` is only treated as a class assertion when there is also `C rdf:type owl:Class` statement. But presence or absence of `owl:NamedIndividual` doesn't affect that rule. Citation for my earlier statement is [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Typing_Constraints_of_OWL_2_DL). OP's problem may well be that some declarations are missing, but I think it's `owl:Class`, `owl:DatatypeProperty` or `owl:ObjectProperty` declarations, and not `owl:NamedIndividual` declarations. We need to see OP's actual RDF output to be sure.

Comment: I agree with @cygri. That line `Individual imagingStudy = createIndiv(generateName("imaging_study_TEST"), model.getResource("http://medicis.univ-rennes1.fr/ontologies/ontospm/OntoMEDIRAD.owl#imaging_study"));` for sure hasn't been executed **before** writing the model to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the soltion

There was a code line in a function used to create an other individual, which was deleting the model and creating a new model.

Thank you for your answers